# validation for change password using ionic2 beta-11 verstion and angualr2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

my password should match to conformation password,for that i am writing validation using formgroup in ionic2 beta11 verstion  and angualr2.here i call one method areEqual to math the password.but i am getting error when i use that.
can any one help me for this.

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="passwordForm">
    <ion-list formGroupName="matchingPassword">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>New Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" value="" formControlName="newpassword" [(ngModel)]="newPasswd" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Re-Enter Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" value="" formControlName="reenterpassword" [(ngModel)]="rePasswd" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    </form>

    <button small (click)="changPassword();">Change Password</button>
```

.ts file:

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private users:Users,public _form: FormBuilder) {
    this.passwordForm = new FormGroup({
          password: new FormGroup({
            oldpassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$')]),
             matchingPassword: new FormGroup({
               newpassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$')]),
               reenterpassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$')]),
              },{validator: this.areEqual})
          })
     });     

  }

   areEqual(group: FormGroup) {
    var valid = false;


    for (name in group.controls) 
    {
      if (val === undefined) 
      {
       var val = group.controls[name].value
      } 
      else 
      {
        if (val !== group.controls[name].value) 
        {
          valid = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (valid) {
      return null;
    }

    return {
      areEqual: true
    };
}
}
```

Comment: I am new to ionic and angular can any one please help me

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Not sure if posting your question twice helps a lot tbh (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529464/validations-for-change-password-using-ionic2-and-angular2)

Comment: TypeScript error: E:/ionic2/post/app/pages/my-password/my-password.ts(33,17): Error TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: (group: FormGroup) => { areEqual: boolean; }; validator: (group: FormGroup) => { a...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: boolean; }'.
  Index signatures are incompatible.
    Type '(group: FormGroup) => { areEqual: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: @Ajeets i assing areEual as boolean ,initially i am giving areEqual as  false,when i give true that time only it can validate .

Comment: @Ajeets that time i am getting this error TypeScript error: E:/ionic2/post/app/pages/my-password/my-password.ts(33,17): Error TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: (group: FormGroup) => { areEqual: boolean; }; validator: (group: FormGroup) => { a...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: boolean; }'. Index signatures are incompatible. Type '(group: FormGroup) => { areEqual: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: your  `areEqual` method will never change the value of `valid`. `valid` is always `false`.